# Insert dynamic version number into cloudbuild image tag

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to feed the version number from a file to my image tag as part of a cloudbuild step.

Can't quite seem to get it working.

**version.txt**

```
0.2.3
```

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_IMAGE_NAME}:$$(cat version.txt)'
      - '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick.

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - -c
      - |-
        docker build \
          --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_IMAGE_NAME}:`cat version.txt` \
          .
```