# Using Google CloudBuild to trigger a Firebase deployment, how can I write a static version file?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, web-deployment, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build

I have a VueJS app hosted on Firebase, and I'm using CloudBuild to build and deploy it.  My ultimate goal is to embed a version number or commit SHA into the footer of the front page, so we can always confirm which version we're seeing in the browser.  Happy to hear alternate implementations, but right now I'm just trying to write a static text file.

I know each step in CloudBuild is a unique container, and only `/workspace` gets held over through each step.  If I execute "pwd," I do see that's where all these steps take place.

I can even write the text file as shown (my date interpolation doesn't work), and see the file exists in the subsequent step.  But after the final deployment, it's not there.

```
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    args: ['-c', "echo \"$REVISION_ID (commit $COMMIT_SHA) deployed on `date`\" >> ./static/version.txt"]
  - name: 'bash'
    args: ['ls', '-lart', './static']
  # Deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
    args: ['run', 'deploy']
```

the ls output shows this:

```
total 56
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 svg
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 styles
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 plugins
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           442 Apr 17 20:52 manifest.json
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 legal
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 js
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 images
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 gifs
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:52 fonts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          6148 Apr 17 20:52 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   12 root     root          4096 Apr 17 20:59 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           132 Apr 17 21:00 version.txt
drwxr-xr-x   10 root     root          4096 Apr 17 21:00 .
```

So I know the version.txt file gets written and persists across steps.

The `npm run deploy` step just runs `firebase deploy`.  The app deploys, but the version.txt file gives a 404.  Notably, I can navigate to <APP_ROOT>/static/manifest.json and open that file in the browser -- but since it is part of the git revision, maybe that doesn't tell me much.

Not sure how to proceed from here.  Am I missing something about how CloudBuild works?  **Is there a better way to do this version thing?**

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64860367/16531441)? This might help.

Comment: That's similar, but not quite the same. That person already has a version file and wants to use it to tag a docker image.  Thank you for your reply!